# Outlook VSTO add-in with form will not create the mail-item

Tags: vb.net, forms, outlook, add-in

I have created an Outlook Add-in (VSTO) that opens a form in which I have multiple controls that give output to use in the E-mail. However when trying to build the solution I get an exception thrown, saying all outlook dialogs should be closed. I believe my Form is the problem but this form is the main form of my add-in, so when closing the form I believe the whole add-in stops.

I tried hiding the form, or setting a timer to create the mail item, in the hopes for the mail item being able to be created but it didn't work.

Comment: If you place code to the events of the controls they will be executed.